# Deadlock in Google Storage API

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm running a spark job on Dataproc which reads lots of files from a bucket and consolidates them to one big file. I'm using `google-api-services-storage 1.29.0` by shading it. Until now it worked fine, consolidating ~20-30K files. Today I tried it with about 5 times as many files and suddenly I'm getting a deadlock (at east I think I am, because it seems that all my executors are waiting indefinitely).
[image]

This is the thread dump:

```
org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.read(NativeSsl.java:416)
org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:547) => holding Monitor(java.lang.Object@1638155334})
java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345) => holding Monitor(java.io.BufferedInputStream@1513035694})
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587) => holding Monitor(sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection@995846771})
sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492) => holding Monitor(sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection@995846771})
java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
com.shaded.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:37)
com.shaded.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:105)
com.shaded.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
com.shaded.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
com.shaded.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
com.shaded.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeMedia(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:380)
com.shaded.google.api.services.storage.Storage$Objects$Get.executeMedia(Storage.java:6189)
com.shaded.google.cloud.storage.spi.v1.HttpStorageRpc.load(HttpStorageRpc.java:584)
com.shaded.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$16.call(StorageImpl.java:464)
com.shaded.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl$16.call(StorageImpl.java:461)
com.shaded.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:89)
com.shaded.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:74)
com.shaded.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:51)
com.shaded.google.cloud.storage.StorageImpl.readAllBytes(StorageImpl.java:461)
com.shaded.google.cloud.storage.Blob.getContent(Blob.java:455)
my.package.with.my.StorageAPI.readFetchedLocation(StorageAPI.java:71)
...
```

Eventually I have to kill the job because nothing happens.
Any idea what is causing it? I tried using both a `ThreadLocal<Storage>` and a single `Storage` instance in my code, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: If you're able to create a new cluster, try setting the property `dataproc:dataproc.conscrypt.provider.enable=false` to disable the conscrypt optimization and see if that changes things. If so, you might consider filing a support ticket with any details you can share about the nature of the workload and project id, cluster uuid, etc., and/or sending info to dataproc-feedback@google.com

Comment: It appears that you're using GCS client directly. Are you handling different error codes (like 429) correctly with expoential backoffs? It is possible you're DOSing GCS servers. The following should work on your cluster `spark.read.csv('gs://...')` and will handle backoffs correctly.

Comment: Just tested this again - the job actually is NOT deadlocked, if I wait enough time it finishes even without exponential-backoff or disabling the conscrypt optimization ... It's just the Spark UI that doesn't show any progress for a long time, so I thought the tasks were hung. Sorry for the false alarm, I will leave this question open because of the recommendation to use exponential backoff when using the Storage sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job was actually NOT deadlocked, it's just the Spark UI that for some reason didn't show any progress of the tasks until the stage finished. I thought nothing was happening but if I do a thread-dump repeatedly then I can see that it's doing stuff.

As tix suggested in a comment, it's probably advisable to implement [exponential backoff](https://carlosbecker.com/posts/exponential-backoff-java8/) when using the Storage library directly, and retry if I get a [`StorageException`](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/storage/StorageException.html) which `isRetryable()`.

Comment: Let me share with you the general reference for [Truncated Exponential Backoff](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/exponential-backoff) in the GCS documentation. It has a broader explanation of the implementation and some examples too.